# How do I find the difference in hours between two time zones?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have this code here that can find the time in two different timezones at the moment. I want to calculate the difference in hours, between the two timezones.

```
def time_caluclator(timezone1, timezone2):

    dt_utcnow = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)

    dt_1 = dt_utcnow.astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezone1))
    dt_2 = dt_utcnow.astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezone2))

    print(dt_1, dt_2)
```

This is the code, and it will print this:

```
2022-05-15 00:44:22.031149+00:00 2022-05-15 01:44:22.031149+01:00
```

(First timezone is Zulu, and the other is WET).

Comment: your code is fine, why not just use `(dt_1-dt_2).total_seconds()/3600` to get the difference in hours?

Answer (score 1):

```py
def time_caluclator(timezone1, timezone2):
    off1 = pytz.timezone(timezone1).utcoffset(datetime.datetime.now())
    off2 = pytz.timezone(timezone2).utcoffset(datetime.datetime.now())
    return (off2 - off1).seconds // 3600
```

Works correct for pytz timezones such as "US/Eastern", "Europe/Moscow".

Comment: calling datetime.now repeatedly creates inaccuracy in the microsecond range. Not that it matters here, it just isn't "clean".

Comment: @FObersteiner I don't understand you talking it doesn't matter because `//`, or because it doesn't affect to algorithm at all. Calling `.utcoffset()` this way or providing two different datetimes will return same result. Try it with `now()` and `12:12:12 12/12/2012`.

Comment: My point is: calling datetime.now multiple times creates *different* timestamps, different in the microsecond range, depending on execution time of the code. OP is interested in *hours difference*, so microseconds don't matter.

Comment: @FObersteiner In this code it doesn't matter at all what datetime used. Again, try `now()` and `12:12:12 12/12/2012`, result will be exactly as using two `now()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do two nested for loops to separate your times into sections by both spaces and ":" so that you can get the individual numbers. Then its just subtraction and maybe a dictionary if you would like to say specifically timezone codes like "EST"

Comment: you definitively do not want nested loops dealing with strings to solve this problem. you have data structures such as datetime and timezone classes that give you methods to solve it efficiently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).